# Where is openoffice.org add-on located after installed (Ubuntu)?

Tags: ubuntu, openoffice-calc, libreoffice-calc, addons

I installed a tool which now appears in Openoffice Calc under `Tools->Add-ons`.

I thought that this tool would appear in `~/.openoffice.org/3/user` directory, but I cannot find it.

I am especially searching for config files of this addon e.g. where it saves its data (the tool ads custom styles for certain cells).

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JoeM, all names starting with dot (as /.openoffice/) are hidden in Linux by default - perhaps that's the reason you cannot find the location.

Try this solution:

1. Go to your **home** folder. Open .openoffice.org2 *[.openoffice.org/3/ in your case]*. This can be done in nautilus just fine. To **view hidden folders** and files (those starting with ‘.’), just hit Control-h.
2. Go into the **user** folder.
3. **Delete or rename** the ‘uno_packages’ folder. I renamed it, personally, so I could put it back if needed.
4. **Start OpenOffice**. It will be just like new.

[[source](http://daniel1992.wordpress.com/2008/02/26/removing-openoffice-extensions/)]

Comment: it as not the problem with hidden files :). I just did not know where to look for ooo extensions. So you're saying they are in uno_packages  folder?